# how to use getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I want to navigate to dashboard screen, if the user logs in from the login screen. My code is like this.

```
// Login Screen

     componentDidUpdate() {
          const { auth, history } = this.props;
          redirectIfAuthenticated(auth.isAuthenticated, history, './dashboard');
       }

       static getDerivedStateFromProps = (nextProps, prevState) => {
          if (nextProps.errors) 
             return { errors: nextProps.errors }

          return { errors: prevState.errors }
       }


// auth util
export const redirectIfAuthenticated = (isAuthenticated, history, screen) => {
   if (isAuthenticated) { 
      history.push(screen);
   }
}
```

this works as expected. I want to know if im doing this in the right way. I replaced componentWillRecieveProps with getDerivedStateFromProps. Now I have to use componentDidUpdate as well to achieve what I did with componentWillRecieveProps. Is this correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is how you should do it. Take a look at the [getDerivedStateFromProps's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Also, you can return null to avoid updating the state so I would change the prevState.errors part into this :

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps = (nextProps, prevState) => {
          if (nextProps.errors) {
             return { errors: nextProps.errors }
          } else {
           return null
          }
       }
```